# Calculate average between mean and 1st standard deviation

Tags: python, numpy, average, mean, standard-deviation

I have an array:

```
import numpy as np

# Create an array of values
values = np.array([41,17,44,36,14,29,33,38,49,39,22,15,46])

# Calculate the mean
mean = np.mean(values)

# Calculate the standard deviation
standard_deviation = np.std(values)
```

How can I calculate the average of values between mean and the 1st standard deviation? I have:

```
# Calculate the average of values between the mean and the first standard deviation
mean_between_mean_and_first_standard_deviation = np.mean(values[(values >= mean) & (values <= standard_deviation)])
print("Average between mean and first standard deviation:", mean_between_mean_and_first_standard_deviation)
```

I get:

```
Average between mean and first standard deviation: nan
```

[image: std]

Comment: You assumed the mean is 0. The standard deviation is a distance from the mean value, so to get the right bound you need to add it to the mean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following graphic should make it clearer. You need to select values that are between `mean` and `mean` plus one times the `standard_deviation`.

```
np.mean(values[(values >= mean) & (values < (mean + 1 * standard_deviation))])
```

Or if you want mid-point, you could do:

```
np.mean([mean, mean + 1 * standard_deviation])
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For example, you could do this:

```
np.mean(values[np.logical_and(values >= mean, values <= mean+standard_deviation)])
```

`values >= mean` evaluates to a boolean array of the same shape as `values` such that it has `True` everywhere the condition is satisfied and `False` otherwise. Similarly, for `values <= mean+standard_deviation`.

What remains is to find where both conditions are satisfied using `np.logical_and()`. This boolean array is then used to compute the mean of `values` only at such indices where the values satisfy both conditions

Comment: You've explained everything but the most important part that you've changed. Consider adding an explanation about why the second inequality needs to be changed.

Comment: you can use the & logic to make sure both conditions are met.

Comment: @JoseLuisLandivarS They are equivalent in this case.